# Two Table but different width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make table header and table data. But facing problem with width on that two tables different.

Here is the example table :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Class</td>
<td>Phone</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and the data here :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>John Reise</td>
<td>Math</td>
<td>123456789</td>
<tr>
<td>Michael Sweirzgez</td>
<td>Information Technology</td>
<td>012345678910</td>
<tr>
```

So when I try to run the code, it will like this :

```
Name | Class | Phone
John Reise | Math | 123456789
```

If I delete the data, width will fit with table header.

I make 2 table, 1 table header and 1 table data cause I want to marquee this data. So table header will keep stay in the top.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you better use `thead` and `tbody` tags?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Class</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John Reise</td>
            <td>Math</td>
            <td>123456789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Sweirzgez</td>
            <td>Information Technology</td>
            <td>012345678910</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can read more about it here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use thead and tbody. Here are the simple examples:

> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp
>
> http://www.idocs.com/tags/tables/_THEAD.html